# How to handle user-server connection

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication

I have a mysql-database where usernamen and a hashed password is stored.

I also have an android app from which a user can 'post' statements and comment statements from others.

I can read these statements with a simple get-request which I send to a php-script on my server. This script gives a json with requested statements as a result and displays them in the app.

Now I wonder how I can implement posting and commenting form users. Do I send the username and the password every time a user does any action?

What is the recommended way to do something like this?

Comment: API key, or session token. These are way more efficient. See also: [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).